# How can I get my BST add method to add nodes past the first two child nodes?

Tags: java, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I'm kinda new to Binary Trees and working on an add method for a simple game. Currently the method replaces the child nodes of the root node every time I add new nodes. How can I get it to add new nodes throughout the tree instead of just replacing the first two child nodes of the root node? This is what I have so far:

```
public boolean add(User friend) {
    User node = friend;
    if (root == null) {
        root = node;
        return true;
    }
    if (node.key() < root.key()) {
        if(root.left == null) {
            root.setLeft(node);
        }
    } else if (node.key() > root.key()) {
        if(root.getRight() == null) {
            root.setRight(node);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Use [this](http://algorithms.tutorialhorizon.com/binary-search-tree-complete-implementation/) as a guide.

Comment: It seems that this tree is part of the `User` class. It is most likely better to create a separate `BinarySearchTree<T>` class, and make your `User` class have a field `private BinarySearchTree<User> friends`. `User::beFriend` would then simply call `friends.add`.

Comment: @VladK. That guide explains trees well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, with binary trees you will be writing recursive functions. Instead of managing the insertion from one function call, you can find the side a node belongs to and hand off the insertion to a recursive function call on that node's side.

Assuming that this function belongs to the class `User`, this should work.

```
public boolean beFriend(User friend) {
    User node = friend;
    if (root == null) {
        root = node;
        return true;
    }
    if (node.getKey() < root.getKey()) {
        if(root.getLeft() == null) {
            root.setLeft(node);
        } else {
            // recursively call beFriend handing insertion to the child
            root.getLeft().beFriend(node);
        }
    } else if (node.getKey() > root.getKey()) {
        if(root.getRight() == null) {
            root.setRight(node);
        } else {
            // recursively call beFriend handing insertion to the child
            root.getRight().beFriend(node); 
        }
    } else { // node.getKey() == root.getKey() so we replace the previous root
        node.setLeft(root.getLeft());
        node.setRight(root.getRight());
        root = node;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Why do you replace the root if the keys are equal, instead of just letting it be? This seems to be missing from your answer: it's a change you made without motivating it.

Comment: I'm not sure how or where the keys are generated so it seemed like the safest bet to me. Worst case, we did a bit of extra work. Best case, it correctly updates with a desired user.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned what class it belongs to, it has it own BinaryTree class and User class seperate that holds the key `getKey()`.